# What am I missing about jquery, aria-disabled, and the :disabled selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wai-aria

Using lines such as

```
$('#myButton').button({ 'disabled' : true });
```

I would expect this to match the ':disabled' CSS selector, but it does not. The button is clearly disabled, but it has the following properties:

```
class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
```

I gather that this `aria-disabled` thing is <strike>an IE vendor prefix</strike> unrelated, but why doesn't it have regular old "disabled"? Have I done something wrong here? I gather from the classes that we're using jQuery UI, which I know very little about (I'm hunting bugs in someone else's code).

Comment: [More about ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA) (it's not a vendor prefix and is not IE-specific).

Comment: [aria attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA) are meant for accessability, and has nothing to do with IE. jQuery UI uses the `ui-button-disabled` class to show that the button is disabled.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-disable

Comment: @adeneo So jQuery UI is just intentionally not CSS selector compatible?

Comment: jQuery UI `.button` can be applied to non-form elements, such as `a href`. The `disabled` HTML attribute [should only be applied to form elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1). By adding `class="ui-state-disabled"`, no invalid HTML is produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `button` isn't being called on a form element, `:disabled` won't select it.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/):

> The :disabled selector should only be used for selecting HTML elements that support the disabled attribute (`<button>`, `<input>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`).

If it's being used, for example, to style an `<a>` tag, you'll have to select for one of the `ui-` classes, e.g. `ui-state-disabled`.

Comment: Or use both in your CSS selector: `button:disabled, button.ui-state-disabled { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the `attr()` function and giving it the value of disabled since I am not aware whether or not disabled=true works.

```
$('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```